# Different output with LibGDX and Stage on various phones

Tags: libgdx

I get different screens on Samsung and LG:

Samsung (as it should be)
! http://www.marcofriedmann.de/right.png

LG:
! http://www.marcofriedmann.de/wrong.png

I tried various viewport types, but nothing changed.
Any clues?
Here is the code:

```
package de.marcofriedmann.slideit.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.LabelStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Stack;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ChangeListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ExtendViewport;

import de.marcofriedmann.slideit.util.Assets;
import de.marcofriedmann.slideit.util.Constants;
import de.marcofriedmann.slideit.util.GameStatistics;
import de.marcofriedmann.slideit.util.IActivityRequestHandler;

public class ScoreScreen extends AbstractGameScreen {
private GameStatistics statistics;
private Stage stage;
private Skin skinSlideIt;
private Skin skinLibgdx;
private Image imgBackground;


public ScoreScreen(Game game, IActivityRequestHandler myRequestHandler,
        GameStatistics statistics) {
    super(game, myRequestHandler);
    this.statistics = statistics;
}

private void rebuildStage() {
    skinSlideIt = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.SKIN_SLIDEIT), new TextureAtlas(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECTS));
    skinLibgdx = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.SKIN_LIBGDX_UI), new TextureAtlas(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_LIBGDX_UI));
    Table layerBackground = buildBackgroundLayer();
    Table layerControls = buildControlsLayer();
    stage.clear();
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    stack.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(stack);
    stack.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    stack.add(layerBackground);
    stack.add(layerControls);

}

private Table buildBackgroundLayer() {
    Table layer = new Table();
    imgBackground = new Image(skinSlideIt, "screenshot_slideit");
    layer.add(imgBackground);
    return layer;
}

private Table buildControlsLayer() {
    LabelStyle labelTitleStyle = new LabelStyle(Assets.instance.fonts.titleFont, Color.WHITE);
    LabelStyle labelNormalStyle = new LabelStyle(Assets.instance.fonts.normalFont, Color.WHITE);
    LabelStyle labelNormalGreenStyle = new LabelStyle(Assets.instance.fonts.normalFont, Color.GREEN);
    Table layer = new Table();
    layer.setFillParent(true);
    layer.top().padTop(50);
    Label actualStatisticsTitle = new Label("Actual Game Statistics ", labelTitleStyle);
    String actualStatisticsText1 = 
            "Number of seconds survived: " + statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualSecondsSurvived +
            "/" + statistics.numSecondsSurvived;
    String actualStatisticsText2 = 
            "Number of waves survived: " + statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualWavesSurvived +
            "/" + statistics.numWavesSurvived;
    String actualStatisticsText3 =  
            "Number of wall collisions: " + statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualWallCollisions + 
            "/" + statistics.numWallCollisions;
    String actualStatisticsText4 = 
            "Number of enemy collisions: " + statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualEnemyCollisions + 
            "/" + statistics.numEnemyCollisions;

    Label actualStatisticsLabel1;
    if (statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualSecondsSurvived > statistics.numSecondsSurvived) {
        actualStatisticsLabel1 = new Label(actualStatisticsText1, labelNormalGreenStyle);
        statistics.numSecondsSurvived = statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualSecondsSurvived;
    } else {
        actualStatisticsLabel1 = new Label(actualStatisticsText1, labelNormalStyle);
    }

    Label actualStatisticsLabel2;
    if (statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualWavesSurvived > statistics.numWavesSurvived) {
        actualStatisticsLabel2 = new Label(actualStatisticsText2, labelNormalGreenStyle);
        statistics.numWavesSurvived = statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualWavesSurvived;
    } else {
        actualStatisticsLabel2 = new Label(actualStatisticsText2, labelNormalStyle);
    }

    Label actualStatisticsLabel3;
    if (statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualWallCollisions > statistics.numWallCollisions) {
        actualStatisticsLabel3 = new Label(actualStatisticsText3, labelNormalGreenStyle);
        statistics.numWallCollisions = statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualWallCollisions;
    } else {
        actualStatisticsLabel3 = new Label(actualStatisticsText3, labelNormalStyle);
    }

    Label actualStatisticsLabel4;
    if (statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualEnemyCollisions > statistics.numEnemyCollisions) {
        actualStatisticsLabel4 = new Label(actualStatisticsText4, labelNormalGreenStyle);
        statistics.numEnemyCollisions = statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualEnemyCollisions;
    } else {
        actualStatisticsLabel4 = new Label(actualStatisticsText4, labelNormalStyle);
    }
    statistics.saveGameStatistics();


    Label overallStatisticsTitle = new Label("Overall Game Statistics ", labelTitleStyle);
    String overallStatisticsText = 
            "Number of games played: " + statistics.numGamesPlayed + "\n" +
            "Number of seconds survived: " + statistics.numSecondsPlayedTotal + "\n" +
            "Number of wall collisions: " + statistics.numWallCollisionsTotal + "\n" +
            "Number of enemy collisions: " + statistics.numEnemyCollisionsTotal;

    Label overallStatisticsLabel = new Label(overallStatisticsText, labelNormalStyle);

    TextButton playButton = new TextButton(" Play ", skinLibgdx);
    playButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            myRequestHandler.showAds(false);
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game, myRequestHandler));
        }
    });

    TextButton resetButton = new TextButton(" Reset ", skinLibgdx);
    resetButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualEnemyCollisions = 0;
            statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualSecondsSurvived = 0;
            statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualWallCollisions = 0;
            statistics.actualGameStatistics.numActualWavesSurvived = 0;
            statistics.numEnemyCollisions = 0;
            statistics.numEnemyCollisionsTotal = 0;
            statistics.numGamesPlayed = 0;
            statistics.numSecondsPlayedTotal = 0;
            statistics.numSecondsSurvived = 0;
            statistics.numWallCollisions = 0;
            statistics.numWallCollisionsTotal = 0;
            statistics.numWavesSurvived = 0;
            statistics.saveGameStatistics();
            rebuildStage();
        }
    });

    layer.add(actualStatisticsTitle);
    layer.add(playButton);
    layer.row();
    layer.add(actualStatisticsLabel1);
    layer.row();
    layer.add(actualStatisticsLabel2);
    layer.row();
    layer.add(actualStatisticsLabel3);
    layer.row();
    layer.add(actualStatisticsLabel4);
    layer.row();
    layer.add(overallStatisticsTitle);
    layer.add(resetButton);
    layer.row();
    layer.add(overallStatisticsLabel);

    return layer;
}

@Override
public void render(float deltaTime) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(deltaTime);
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, false);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    stage = new Stage(new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    rebuildStage();
    myRequestHandler.showAds(true);
}



@Override
public void hide() {
    stage.dispose();
    skinSlideIt.dispose();
    skinLibgdx.dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source textures in your font are too large for the low resolution screen of the LG phone you're testing on. There are a few ways to work around this. Here are a couple of alternatives:

- Create a smaller resolution font and load that instead on devices that have low resolution screens.
- Use ExtendViewport, but don't pass the constructor the actual screen dimensions from `getHeight()` and `getWidth()`. Instead, give it the minimum dimensions you know are necessary to get your entire UI to show. It will be shrunk to fit on smaller screens. You will probably want to set your min filter on your font to MipMapLinearNearest or MipMapLinearLinear. The second option looks better across a wider range of devices but will potentially cause a frame-rate hit. And the mag filter needs to be Linear.

Comment: StretchViewport worked better for me. What really did the trick, was using other dimensions for the width/height.I used 800x600 like in the desktop project which caused the strange behaviour. For min filter i also hat to use Linear because the other to didn't word. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: StretchViewport might look weird on devices with a different aspect ratio than what you're testing on, because the UI will be distorted. If you don't use mipmapping, performance may suffer on lower resolution devices, or at least the text won't look crisp.